# Cause Of Depakote Weight Gain & Increased Appetite Side Effects

Tags: side-effects, weight-gain, appetite

Depakote (Sodium valproate) lists weight gain and increased appetite as side effects. I want to fix the underlying cause of Depakote having these side effects. What are the reason it increases appetites and causes weight gain ( other than weight gain being caused from the former ) ? Is there some biological thing that Depakote interacts with in the body that increases appetite and weight?

How would I next time approach researching myself of the underlying cause of the side affect? a side affect? What medical resource would I be best to reference?

This study is a start with no definite conclusion: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2753432/

Comment: There's no easy fix, as the problem is likely multifactorial. More info [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1467-789X.2010.00800.x) and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0920121121002394).